# Unable to find web Element, Elements change based on field highlighting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to find the Element, tried few ways but unable to get to the element

**Picture 1:**

`id="1_s_1_l_MTO_Transaction_Type"` and `Class=""` (is empty)
In the picture, the highlighted HTML (Document_For) is the next field and you can see Class being added as `class="edit-cell ui-state-highlight`

[image]

**Picture 2:**

The desired field is highlighted in this picture and `id="1_s_1_l_MTO_Transaction_Type"` and `Class="edit-cell ui-state-highlight"` and New HTML is added 
`<input id="1_MTO_Transaction_Type"...........`

[image]

**I tried the below:**

`driver.findElement(By.id("1_s_1_l_MTO_Transaction_Type")).click();`

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//tr[starts-with(@class,'ui-widget-content') and @role='row']//td[id='1_s_1_l_MTO_Transaction_Type']"))).click();`

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//tr[@id='1']/td[id='1_s_1_l_MTO_Transaction_Type']"))).click();`

All the above gave me Unable to find element

**Picture 3:**

More HTML to figure out how to find element

It will be a great Help as I have a series of Elements to find in the same way.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to click on the 'Transaction Type' cell based on the row number?

Comment: Transaction type is what I want to click or Sendkeys with a value, I did not try with row number, I added above what I tried but no luck.

Comment: can you check the size with `//td[contains('Transaction_Type')]` xpath.

Comment: Sorry was away from machine, I tried that and got this error

`Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //td[contains('Transaction_Type')] because of the following error:
Error: Function contains expects at least2 arguments, 1 given`

Comment: Tried again with text() 

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//td[contains(text(),'Transaction_Type')]"))).getSize();`  

**and got error** 

`Unable to find element with xpath == //td[contains(text(),'Transaction_Type')]`

Comment: Sorry, I ment `//td[contains(@id,'Transaction_Type')]`

Comment: I got 
`Setting configurations
(104, 32)`

And actually .click for the same highlighted the value. Will try and expand it tomorrow. Will let you know what happened.

Comment: now try to click on the element by replacing `.getSize()` with `.click`. If that works then I will give the rest of the steps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked for that Field and also few more subsequent similar fields.
`// Select Transaction Type
String Transaction_Type = ExcelUtils.getCellData(8, 2);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//td[contains(@id,'Transaction_Type')]"))).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("s_1_2_47_0_icon")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/div[contains(text(), '" + Transaction_Type + "')]")).click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Transaction Type using the id and follow the code below.

```
// Select Transaction Type 
String Transaction_Type = ExcelUtils.getCellData(8, 2); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//td[contains(@id,'Transaction_Type')]"))).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("s_1_2_47_0_icon")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/div[contains(text(), '" + Transaction_Type + "')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the column and click on an index (as i'm seeing, when the column cell is clicked, the input field is created, so you have to click it first)

Try it like this (this is C#, java below):

```
List<IWebElement> TransactionTypeFields => driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td[id*='Transaction_type']"));

IWebElement TransactionTypeInput => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td[id*='Transaction_type'] input"));

public void TypeInTransactionTypeCell(string value, int index)
{
    TransactionTypeFields[index].Click();
    TransactionTypeInput.SendKeys(value);
}
```

in java, using your logic, should be something like this (there may be some syntax errors as im using notepad++):

```
public void TypeInTransactionTypeCell(string value, int index)
{
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[id*='Transaction_type']")).get(index).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[id*='Transaction_type'] input")).sendKeys(value);
}
```

Let me know if it works!